# How to scope a ChangeNotifier to some routes using Provider?

Tags: flutter

I have a ChangeNotifier, and I would like to share it between multiple routes but not **all** routes:

[image]

Page1 is my first page. I need share data of ChangeNotifierProvider with Page2, Page3 and Page only and on enter Page1 call dispose of my ChangeNotifierProvider.

How can I do this using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)?

Answer (score 4):

To do so, the easiest solution is to have *one provider* per route, such that instead of:

```dart
Provider(
  builder: (_) => SomeValue(),
  child: MaterialApp(),
)
```

you have:

```dart
final value = SomeValue();

MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    '/foo': (_) => Provider.value(value: value, child: Foo()),
    '/bar': (_) => Provider.value(value: value, child: Bar()),
    '/cannot-access-provider': (_) => CannotAccessProvider(),
  }
)
```

It is, on the other hand, not possible to have your model "automatically disposed".

`provider` is not able in such a situation to know that it is safe to dispose of the object.

Comment: But I have a problem, the provider of Page2, Page3 and Page4 must be shared with each other

Comment: What's the current behavior

Comment: I need page 2, page 3 and page 4, if I share with ChangeNotifier, but page 1 is not, it is first in the stack.

Comment: Again that's exactly what this answer does.

Comment: And how to make the value automatically disposed in this case? That is what I been trying to figure out. Do I really need to make my own solution for this? Shouldn`t that be a very common use case?